# How to filter in a core result webpart on columnA is not empty or null?

Tags: web-part, search

How to filter in a core result webpart on a column which is not null or empty?

I try this but is not working:

```
ContentType="Project portal" and SRExperienceRecord="True" and columnA Not ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Search queries cannot return null values. If a value is null it is not included in the index. You have to find another approach or use Content Enrichment to detect the null value and set a second fields value indicating that your value is Noll. This is one case were Search Query is not like SQL.

Comment: what about check if a date column is larger as 02-02-2015? something like this: and column > "02-02-2015"

Comment: Sure, you just can't test for null.